# Whats wrong with this foreach loop ? PHP

Tags: php, string, foreach

Sry, it was just confused that a dot requires the string to be defined. Bad that a answer dropped so far that I couldn´t delete it...

The $content string will be written into an html file. When I run this I get this error, whats wrong with it ?

Notice: Undefined variable: content in C:\wamp\www\serverstatus\example.php on line 66

```
foreach ($ips as $id => $ip) {
    $content .= '
    <div class="server">
        <div class="head">
            <h2>'.$id.'</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <ul>
                <li class="status"></li>
                <li class="ping"></li>
                <li class="player"></li>
                <li class="version"></li>
                <li class="motd"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
';
```

Comment: You're appending to an undefined variable the first iteration through the loop. set `$content = '';` before the loop.

Comment: which one is line 66?

Comment: @Snowburnt `$content .= '` <== that one i reckon!

Comment: @MikeB You should repost your comment as an answer 'cause IT IS the answer.

Comment: @aefxx Nah, I don't think this question belongs here because it's about a simple notice. I'm 110% there's another question that better explains all this. Whoring for rep doesn't interest me. Clearly that doesn't stop everyone else...

Comment: @MikeB My I recommend you'd close the question, then?

Comment: @DannyHearnah Just saying, would have been nice to give a bit more of an indication in the question.

Comment: yeah sry, I was confused about this notice, because it didn´t happend before I added the dot after $content. So I thought something else is wrong, sry for the Question.

Answer (score 4):

Just set the variable to an empty string before you use it. You can't use `.=` on a variable that does not exist yet:

```
$content = '';   // set it to empty string
```

Comment: just got it myself, sry for the question. I will accept it in 12 min. when it is allowed. I was confused because this didn´t happend before I set the "." between §content and "="

Answer (score 1):

Make the code fit into one line and define `$content` at start

```
 $content='';

foreach ($ips as $id => $ip) {
$content .= '  <div class="server">      <div class="head">           <h2>'.$id.'</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <ul>
            <li class="status"></li>
            <li class="ping"></li>
            <li class="player"></li>
            <li class="version"></li>
            <li class="motd"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
';
```

Answer (score 1):

You are appending a variable that does not already exist. Add the following before the `foreach`:

```
$content = "";
```

Futhermore, you have not closed the `foreach`, don't forget the curly brace at the end:

```
$content = "";

foreach($ips as $id => $ip) {
    $content .= '<div class="server">';
    $content .= '<div class="head">';
    $content .= '<h2>'.$id.'</h2>';
    $content .= '</div>';
    $content .= '<div class="content">';
    $content .= '<ul>';
    $content .= '<li class="status"></li>';
    $content .= '<li class="ping"></li>';
    $content .= '<li class="player"></li>';
    $content .= '<li class="version"></li>';
    $content .= '<li class="motd"></li>';
    $content .= '</ul>';
    $content .= '</div>';
    $content .= '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is as the error said, you are using an undefined variable - content:

So all you need to do is to define it, this code will work:

```
$content = ''; //Add this code
foreach ($ips as $id => $ip) {
$content .= '
<div class="server">
    <div class="head">
        <h2>'.$id.'</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <ul>
            <li class="status"></li>
            <li class="ping"></li>
            <li class="player"></li>
            <li class="version"></li>
            <li class="motd"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
';
```